# Scrapy:How to print request referrer

Tags: python, scrapy

Is it possible to get the request referrer from the response object in parse function?

10x

Answer (score 46, accepted):

HTTP `Referer` field is set up by HTTP client in request headers, **not in response headers**, as this header tells server where did client come from to current page.

It would be rather weird to receive http `Referer` header in response.

But when talking about `scrapy`, there's a reference to `Request` object on which the `Response` was generated, in response's `request` field, so the next call result:

```
response.request.headers.get('Referer', None)
```

can contain `Referer` header if it was set when making request.

Comment: you are right, but thought maybe scrapy stores this info in the response as well.

Comment: 10x, I will be using this.
where did you read about this?
does it return the referrer as string?

Comment: @user1537701, headers can be either strings (for single-value headers) or lists of strings (for multi-value headers), about response.request, as far as I remember it should be documented in Response class documentation.

Comment: @user1537701, if it helped, please mark this question as answered so other people could get help too.

Comment: It actually works after replacing 'Referrer' by 'Referer' - could you update the answer?

Comment: i added `str()` around it so it could be saved used in yield output to json

Answer (score 3):

The question above was asked a long time ago, and it has been answered well.

However, I thought I would add a different answer in case the answer by Rostyslav Dzinko does not apply/work in your case.

Let's say that you have 2 different parser methods:

1. one parser (Let's call it parser_A) simply parses the list of
   articles (list page) to extract link info and others.
2. Another parser (Let's call it parser_B) extracts article info from the target article (article page).

If you cannot get the url (referer url) for the list of articles (list page) once you are in the parser_B, you can set headers field in parser_A, then send it to parser_B as the following example:

```
yield scrapy.Request(url=article_page_url, callback=self.parser_B, dont_filter=True, headers={'referer_url': list_page_url})
```

And, in parser_B method, you can do the following to obtain the list page's url:

```
print(response.request.headers.get('referer_url'))
```

Hope this helps those who needed help.