# How to add Headers to Scrapy CrawlSpider Requests?

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm working with the CrawlSpider class to crawl a website and I would like to modify the headers that are sent in each request.  Specifically, I would like to add the referer to the request.

As per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12054958/scrapyhow-to-print-request-referrer/12055059#12055059), I checked

```
response.request.headers.get('Referer', None)
```

in my response parsing function and the `Referer` header is not present.  I assume that means the Referer is not being submitted in the request (unless the website doesn't return it, I'm not sure on that).

I haven't been able to figure out how to modify the headers of a request.  Again, my spider is derived from CrawlSpider.  Overriding CrawlSpider's `_requests_to_follow` or specifying a `process_request` callback for a rule will not work because the referer is not in scope at those times.

Does anyone know how to modify request headers dynamically?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have to enable the `SpiderMiddleware` that will populate the `referer` for responses.  See the [documentation](https://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html#module-scrapy.contrib.spidermiddleware.referer) for `scrapy.contrib.spidermiddleware.referer.RefererMiddleware`

In short, you need to add this middleware to your project's settings file.

```
SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
'scrapy.contrib.spidermiddleware.referer.RefererMiddleware': True,
}
```

Then in your response parsing method, you can use, `response.request.headers.get('Referrer', None)`, to get the referer.

Comment: RefererMiddleware is active by default in BASE_Settings , there is no need to activate them in your spider settings .

Comment: @akhterwahab Hmm. I didn't have referers in my request headers until I added the above to my project settings, which hadn't been previously modified. I do see that the default for the setting is true. Nevertheless they weren't working for me.

Comment: btw:  response.request.headers.get('Referer', None) is the correct usage.  'Referrer' will not give correct results.

Comment: Can you add a cookie with every request using this method??

Comment: @ParthapratimNeog yes you can add using `headers={"Cookie":"ubid-acbuk=253-3565238-8236411; session-id=256-4008452-7910856"}`

Answer (score 23):

You can pass `REFERER` manually to each [request](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request) using `headers` argument:

```
yield Request(parse=..., headers={'referer':...})
```

RefererMiddleware [does the same](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/016c7e92d1d2893e7a8ce61c7f2e76818e71d019/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/referer.py#L291), automatically taking the referrer url from the previous response.

Comment: Great, I will keep that in mind for the future.  In the current setup, I'm not creating requests manually (my rules are taking care of that job).