# Getting most relevant content from page

Tags: xpath, web-scraping

I need to create a universal web **scraper** to parse articles on the different websites. Of course, I know about XPath, but I want to try to make it universal for any website despite the HTML markup of a page.

I need to determine whether there is an article on the page and if it is - parse a text of title, body and tags (if exists).

Frankly speaking, my knowledge in DS is not very huge, but I assume this task (determine whether it is article, and parsing only needed parts) is possible to solve.

What tools should I use? Any help?

Actually, for the second task, I need to implement something similar that google chrome mobile does. When page is not optimised for mobile, then propose to show the page in adaptive mode (just title, and main content).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Python, some libraries to look at are:

- [scrapy](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/index.html), which scrapes data and can extract some of the results) and,
- [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/), which is more geared towards the extraction part itself.

It is possible to request a version of a website (e.g. for Chrome, Safari, Mobile, old-school systems) by creating a custom header for your scraper.
HAve a look at [the relevant documentation](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html?highlight=header), and you can get an idea of how to use headers in scrapy [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220174/how-to-add-headers-to-scrapy-crawlspider-requests).

I do not know of any more specialised tools. Your tasks are more analytical and are typically not performed with the use of models for estimating e.g. what content is where on a webpage. This might be an intersting research direction though; to see if you can create a model that generalises across many websites to extract the desired content.

That leads me on to my last point, which is to say that creating a single scraper that works for any website *containing your artile type) is not usually possible. People create websites differently, however they see fit, which means they also change them. This usually leads to a good scraper requiring constant updates as time (and developers) moves on.

**EDIT:**

Then if you have lots of labelled examples, it might be possible to train a model. The challenge might be the look-back range of the model. For example, a typical LSTM model is given a parameter that tells it how far to look back into the past. It is stored within its memory internally. In your case, you might be looking for a start and end HTML tag of an article, to then extract just that part. These tahs could be thousands of words apart. Something a standard LSTM might not be fit to retain and use.

If you could pose your problem a little differently, then there are other approaches that might be plausible. E.g., you could make it a "question-answer" problem, by saying: I have this HTML, where is the article content? If that sounds ok for your use-case, [have a look here for some model based approaches](https://rajpurkar.github.io/SQuAD-explorer/).

Comment: Thanks, I know about scrappy and soup, they are great for usual parsing. But my aim is to using ML and DS get article content from html. Do you understand? We need to recognize huge part of text on a page, in most cases - it is article`s body.