# Response.url and refer url scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

```
2020-11-09 12:13:08 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://example.com/books/adventure/book1/index.html> (referer: example.com/books/adventure/index.html)
```

If anyone is familiar with scarpy, you know that `https://example.com/books/adventure/book1/index.html` is called `response.url`. However, I want to get the refer link `example.com/books/adventure/index.html`, does anyone know what it's called.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scrapy:How to print request referrer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12054958/scrapyhow-to-print-request-referrer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create the referer in your header.

Ideally it needs to be created by you, i.e you will already have it and you don't need to get it from the response.

eg.

```
    headers={'Referer':'example.com/books/adventure/index.html'}
```

Hope that helps?